# Getting the user's browsing history's URLs

Tags: python, web

I was wondering if it is possible to get all the URL's from the history page of a person, perhaps with python (using selenium, or any other tool)?

Comment: Will your code run server or client-side?

Comment: the code will run on the client's side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not possible for two reasons:

1. Python is a server side language that is not executed in the user's browser
2. Even if you did use a client side language that runs in the user's browser (i.e. JavaScript), security restrictions prevent this

Think of the implications if this were possible: Would you want any company whose website you are accessing to be able to spy on you like that?

Comment: I am not agree with you. You need to checkout desktime software. They are instantly fetching which url you are visiting with their software without any browser extention or client side code on browser.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, especially with python. The only thing that could potentially work is JavaScript. But a history is generally protected by the browser.

The only thing that comes close to this is [Mozilla's History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). However, even this would work only in Firefox.

Hope it helps.